# Redirection loop when enabling Virtualhost HTTPS to HTTPS redirection

Tags: apache-2.2, https, website, redirection

I am using Apache sites to redirect HTTPS subdomain to other HTTPS subdomain but when I enable it I get a Redirection loop on the browser.

The initial situation is the following:

https://example1.domain.com and https://example2.domain.com shows the same content. The VirtualHost configuration is the following:

`<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example1.domain.com
        ServerAlias example2.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /srv/www/example1.domain.com/current/public
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile    /srv/ssl/certs/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /srv/ssl/certs/server.keyal
</VirtualHost>`

The ideal situation would be example2.domain.com redirects to example1.domain.com and the application has only one access point. I am trying with the following VirtualHohst configuration:

`<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAlias example2.domain.com
        Redirect permanent / https://example1.domain.com/
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile    /srv/ssl/certs/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /srv/ssl/certs/server.key
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example1.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /srv/www/example1.domain.com/current/public
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile    /srv/ssl/certs/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /srv/ssl/certs/server.key
</VirtualHost>`

But at this point I get a redirection loop on the browser.

Some ideas about the problem?

Comment: Did you try changing ServerAlias example2.domain.com to ServerName example2.domain.com ? It's not an alias there technically.

Comment: WoW! That did the trick. Many thanks!!! I use the same scheme in several HTTP VirtualHost files and works fine. Which can be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

> ServerAlias example2.domain.com

to

> ServerName example2.domain.com

It's not an alias there technically. I don't use Apache much anymore but it seems like because you told it it was an Alias, it keeps looking for a ServerName, hence the redirect loop.